# Filtering JSON by ngModel

Tags: json, angular, filter

I am currently filtering my JSON, it works fine if I filter it with a hard coded value.

Code Sample:

```
this.names= this.names.filter(function (name) {
    return name.last== 'lastname';
  });
```

It returns the object where the value of the last key is 'lastname'. However, when I use a variable to filter

Code:

```
this.names= this.names.filter(function (name) {
    return name.last== this.selectedLname';
  });
```

It shows cannot read property of 'selectedLname' in console error, but the selectedLname has a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `this` keyword in that refer to that function object. Try changing your function to arrow function and it will work.

```
this.names = this.names.filter((name) => {
    return name.last== this.selectedLname';
});
```

```js
var data= [ {
  firstName:'abc',
  lastName: 'xyz'
},
{
  firstName:'yut',
  lastName: 'eueo'
}];
var seachKey = 'xyz'
var result = data.filter((item) => item.lastName == seachKey);
console.log(result);
```

Check this out

Comment: Now it shows this.names.filter is not a function in the console

Comment: Can you show how you are invoking this function?

Comment: Upon (click) on the button in footer

Comment: Above solution should work, The only reason I can think if you are getting above error is when your names array is null. Please check that